# Composer installed, get env: php: No such file or directory

Tags: composer-php, mamp

I am using MAMP on macOS 12 (Monterey), so I want to run through MAMP to use PHP. Therefor I added this alias:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
alias phpmamp='/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin/php'
```

Then I ran:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | phpmamp
```

Which resulted in:

```
Composer (version 2.4.2) successfully installed to: /Users/johnmiles/composer.phar
Use it: php composer.phar
```

Then I made it available globally:

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

But when I run `composer` I get:

```
env: php: No such file or directory
```

So how do I tell composer to use phpmamp?

Answer (score 1):

Within the Terminal, run `vim ~/.bash_profile`

Type i and then paste the following at the top of the file:

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.0.8/bin:$PATH
```

Hit ESC, Type `:wq`, and hit Enter

In Terminal, run `source ~/.bash_profile`

In Terminal, type in which php again and look for the updated string. If everything was successful, It should output the new path to MAMP PHP install.

In case it doesn't output the correct path, try closing the terminal window (exit fully) and open again, it should apply the changes (Restart in short).

Comment: alternatively you can complete the install by modifying the first line of composer.phar providing the path to the executable. composer uses `/usr/bin/env`  with the `php` positional argument, you can replace it with the executable of your choice, e.g. `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin/php` so that it works well for the location you put it to (`/usr/local/bin/composer`) and then its already configured for the whole system. The composer installer does *not* offer an option for that thought (compare `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | phpmamp -- --help`).